# Is there a way to reuse SQL fragments in annotation-based MyBatis/iBatis?

Tags: java, annotations, mybatis, ibatis

MyBatis has this great feature of **reusable SQL fragments** in XML-based definition, such as:

```
<mapper namespace="com.company.project.dao.someDao">

    <sql id="whereDate">
        WHERE date(`time`) BETWEEN #{startDate} AND #{endDate}
    </sql>  

    <sql id="someOtherSqlFragment">
        ...
    </sql>

    <select id="getSomeData"
            resultType="SomeClass"
            parameterType="DateParam" >
        SELECT some_column, another_column
    </select>

        FROM some_table

        <include refid="whereDate"/>

        <include refid="otherSqlFragment"/>

    </select>

</mapper>
```

Is there a way to define and use such fragments in the annotation-based definition of the queries or is there no way around XMLs for this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XML elements for dynamic SQL in the annotation value if it is embedded in `<script>` XML element:

```
@Select("<script>SELECT ...</script>")
```

But using `<include>` element will trigger a SQL Mapper Configuration parse exception, caused by:

> org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Unknown element
>    in SQL statement.   at
>   org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.XMLScriptBuilder.parseDynamicTags

If you check the `nodeHandlers` method in class `org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException`, you will note the supported elements are:

- trim
- where
- set
- foreach
- if
- choose
- when
- otherwise
- bind

Then: NO, including fragment in annotation-based queries is not possible.